# Git: Is there a quick way to see when was the last time that git merge master was done on the current working branch?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I'm usually working on a branch that is diverged from master.  So while I'm developing things, I perform `git merge master` once in a while.  And sometimes I wanna know when was the last time, I did `git merge master` on that branch.  I know I can do `git log` and look for "Merge branch 'master'", and see the Date of the commit… but if there is a magic, I'd like to know!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
git show :/"Merge branch 'master'"
```

Comment: interesting, I didn't know rev-parse understood regexen. I'm gonna use that in the future (though not for this :) just to replace some of the `git log --grep` style searches)

Answer (score 4):

I personally like to inspect the difference in revision trees:

```
git log --graph --left-right --cherry-pick --oneline branch1...branch2
```

Also, in the 'magic' department there is

```
git show-branch 
git show-branch branch1 branch2
git show-branch --all # which does all of the above and more
```

And finally,

```
git merge-base branch1 branch2
```

to name the *base* revision that would be merged *from*

---

Notes:

- replace `branch1` and `branch2` as appropriate for your project
- you can alias those commands if you like them: http://progit.org/book/ch2-7.html#git_aliases
- the `--cherry-pick` options carries a rare kind of `magic`:

> ```
> --cherry-pick
> ```
>
> Omit any commit that introduces the same change as another commit on the "other side" when the set of commits are limited with symmetric difference.
>
> For example, if you have two branches, A and B, a usual way to list all commits on only one side of them is with --left-right, like the example above in the description of that option. It however shows the commits that were cherry-picked from the other branch (for example, "3rd on b" may be cherry-picked from branch A). With this option, such pairs of commits are excluded from the output.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`git merge-base`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-merge-base.html) to get the common ancestor, and display the results.

Something like this:

`git merge-base HEAD master | git show  --pretty`